# Dictionary returning wrong value for key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

My Dictionary does not appear to be returning the correct value:

```
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT VALUES"))
            {
                string AttachementID = line.Split('(', ',')[1];
                string FileName = AttachementsDictionary[AttachementID];
                string BacklogScrumID = BacklogLookupDictionary[AttachementID];
                BacklogItem Story = BacklogItemDictionary[BacklogScrumID];
                Product Product = ProductDictionary[Story.ProductScrumId];
            }
        }
```

The issue is occurring at:

```
BacklogItem Story = BacklogItemDictionary[BacklogScrumID];
```

Here is the simple class:

```
public class BacklogItem
{
    public string ProductScrumId { get; set; }
    public string StoryTitle { get; set; }
}
```

The value being passed is: -324048562862518297

[image]

However, instead of returning the associated BacklogItem object it is returning the very 1st one in the dictionary:

[image]
[image]

The key -324048562862518297 != -922008489156936615 so why is the wrong object being returned?

Edit: How the dictionary is populated:

```
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT"))
            {
                AttachementsDictionary.Add(line.Split('(', ',')[1], line.Split('\'', '\'')[1]);
            }
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO BACKLOGITEM_ATTACHMENT"))
            {
                if (!BacklogLookupDictionary.ContainsKey(line.Split('(', ',')[1]))
                {
                    BacklogLookupDictionary.Add(line.Split(',', ')')[1], line.Split('(', ',')[1]);
                }
            }
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO BACKLOGITEMEJB VALUES"))//-324048562862518297
            {
                CurrentBacklogItem.ProductScrumId = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")[7];
                CurrentBacklogItem.StoryTitle = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")[12];
                BacklogItemDictionary.Add(line.Split('(', ',')[1], CurrentBacklogItem);
            }
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO PRODUCTEJB VALUES"))
            {
                CurrentProduct.ProductName = line.Split('\'', '\'')[1].Replace(@"'", string.Empty);
                CurrentProduct.StoryPrefix = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")[4].Replace(@"'", string.Empty);

                ProductDictionary.Add(line.Split('(', ',')[1], CurrentProduct);
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is the dictionary being populated?

Comment: yeah, are you sure that the same item isn't in two places in the dictionary?

Comment: It looks like the same value is mapped to two different keys in the dictionary. What is the dictionary entry for the key `"324048562862518297"`?

Comment: Your 'Story' class probably has an incorrect implementation of the Equals() and GetHashcode() methods

Comment: @user469104: No, the `BacklogItem` class (which Story is an instance of) isn't used as a key in the dictionary, so that wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Lee when creating the dictionary is there a way to see when repeated values are entered on multiple keys?

Comment: @DavidTunnell - You could do something like `dict.GroupBy(p => p.Value, p => p.Key).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)` to find all values mapped by multiple keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a matter of bad inputs. Either you have lines that match more than one of your `if` statements (because there aren't line breaks between INSERT statements), or there are multiple insert statements that associate a different dictionary key value with the same ProductScrumId and StoryTitle.